# Preview Word / Excel Files in Files Explorer without MS Office

Tags: windows-explorer, preview

I am lecturer in a university, we are forced to use WPS Office as the institute cannot
bear the expenses of MS Office, so we have lost the defualt feature in windows to preview
Word/Excel files after we turn on the preview pane in Windows File Explorer. Last 2 days
I spent searching for some alternate file explorer but even if some vendor claims the preview
its either not available for office documents or doesnt have the preview feature at all.

The preview is badly needed by faculty, since often we go thrugh a lot of word files, by just
clicking them in windows file explorer or using arrow keys to navigate through.

Please suggest some working solution

Comment: Try Avantstar Quick View Plus    http://www.avantstar.com/quick-view-plus-2020#fndtn-overview

Comment: Thank you for suggestion, its already not a free app. Also it has performance issues (very delayed navigation and/or preview that cannot be used on the fly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I can develop winforms applications, so I tried hard with various solutions.

Most of them were not free, so were not useable, then pandoc converter helped me
still it was not very good

So I moved to Syncfusion community edition
it is already free and its libraries allow to convert all major word processor
based formats and its result was same as other non-free solutions. I am sharing the source here if someone needs (its a Winforms code behind file), and it allows to preview all major word processing based formats
(.doc, .docx, .rtf, .dot, .odt)
Excel or ppt formats not supported, but anyone can extend it to include those as well

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using CefSharp;
using CefSharp.WinForms;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO;
using Syncfusion.DocIO;
using Syncfusion.DocIO.DLS;
using Syncfusion.DocToPDFConverter;
using Syncfusion.OfficeChart;
using Syncfusion.OfficeChartToImageConverter;
using Syncfusion.Pdf;
using NPOI;
using NPOI.HSSF.UserModel;
using NPOI.SS.UserModel;
using NPOI.XSSF.UserModel;

namespace DocPreViewerNew
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public ChromiumWebBrowser wb;
        List<string> AllFiles = new List<string>();
        List<string> AllNamesOnly = new List<string>();
        string SelectedFile;
        string NameOnly;
        int ResizeUnit = 40;
        string[] SourcePath;
        int PDFZoomUnit = 100;
        string XLPath = "";

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitializeChromium();            
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.KeyPreview = true;
            //lbFiles.Width = Convert.ToInt32(this.Width * 0.23);
            //panel2.Location = new Point(lbFiles.Location.X +Convert.ToInt32(this.Width * 0.23)+5, panel2.Location.Y);
            //panel2.Width = Convert.ToInt32(this.Width*0.75);

            if (Properties.Settings.Default.PreviewMode.Equals("HTML")) rbHTML.Checked = true;
            else rbPDF.Checked = true;

            PDFZoomUnit = Convert.ToInt32(txtPDFZoom.Text.Trim());

           
        }

        private void lbFiles_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {               
                PDFZoomUnit = Convert.ToInt32(txtPDFZoom.Text.Trim());
                wb.LoadUrl("about:blank"); lblFCount.Text = "";
                if (lbFiles.SelectedIndices.Count == 1)
                {
                    // Two string lists
                    SelectedFile = AllFiles[lbFiles.SelectedIndex];
                    NameOnly = AllNamesOnly[lbFiles.SelectedIndex];
                    lblFCount.Text = "File No: " + (lbFiles.SelectedIndex+1).ToString();

                    if (NameOnly.EndsWith(".docx") || NameOnly.EndsWith(".doc") || NameOnly.EndsWith(".rtf"))
                    {
                        //Loads the template document
                        WordDocument document = new WordDocument(SelectedFile, FormatType.Automatic);

                        if (rbHTML.Checked == true)
                        {
                            //Saves the document as Html file
                            document.Save(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\" + "output.html", FormatType.Html);
                            wb.LoadUrl(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\" + "output.html");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //Initializes the ChartToImageConverter for converting charts during Word to pdf conversion
                            document.ChartToImageConverter = new ChartToImageConverter();
                            //Sets the scaling mode for charts (Normal mode reduces the Pdf file size)
                            document.ChartToImageConverter.ScalingMode = ScalingMode.Normal;
                            //Creates an instance of the DocToPDFConverter - responsible for Word to PDF conversion
                            DocToPDFConverter converter = new DocToPDFConverter();
                            //Sets true to enable the fast rendering using direct PDF conversion.
                            converter.Settings.EnableFastRendering = true;
                            //Converts Word document into PDF document
                            PdfDocument pdfDocument = converter.ConvertToPDF(document);
                            //Saves the PDF file to file system
                            pdfDocument.Save(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\" + "output.pdf");
                            //Closes the instance of document objects
                            wb.LoadUrl(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\" + "output.pdf#zoom=" + PDFZoomUnit.ToString() + "&toolbar=0");
                            pdfDocument.Close(true);
                            //Closes the document 
                            document.Close();
                        }
                    }
                    else if (NameOnly.EndsWith(".pdf"))
                    {
                        wb.LoadUrl(SelectedFile + "#zoom=" + PDFZoomUnit.ToString() + "&toolbar=0");
                    }
                    else if (NameOnly.EndsWith(".txt"))
                        wb.LoadUrl(SelectedFile);
                    else
                    {
                        File.WriteAllText(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\" + "error1.html", "<h3>** Some Error **</h3><h4>Format not supported</h4>");
                        wb.LoadUrl(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\" + "error1.html");
                    }

                }
                else if (lbFiles.SelectedIndices.Count > 1)
                {
                    lblFCount.Text = "Total Selected: " + lbFiles.SelectedIndices.Count.ToString();
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                File.WriteAllText(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\" + "error1.html", "<h3>** Some Error **</h3><h4>" + ex.Message + "</h4>");
                wb.LoadUrl(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\" + "error1.html");
            }

        }

        private void btnMoveSelected_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           
        }



        //********
        #region UtilityFuntions


        private void lbFiles_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            StartMaximized(AllFiles[lbFiles.SelectedIndex]);
        }

        private void lbFiles_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
                StartMaximized(AllFiles[lbFiles.SelectedIndex]);
            else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Delete)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (lbFiles.SelectedIndex != -1)
                    {
                        var confirmResult = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure to delete this item ??", "Confirm Delete!!", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);

                        if (confirmResult == DialogResult.Yes)
                        {
                            wb.LoadUrl("about:blank");
                            FileSystem.DeleteFile(AllFiles[lbFiles.SelectedIndex], UIOption.OnlyErrorDialogs, RecycleOption.SendToRecycleBin);
                            AllFiles.RemoveAt(lbFiles.SelectedIndex);
                            AllNamesOnly.RemoveAt(lbFiles.SelectedIndex);
                            lbFiles.SelectedIndexChanged -= lbFiles_SelectedIndexChanged;
                            lbFiles.Items.RemoveAt(lbFiles.SelectedIndex);
                            lbFiles.SelectedIndexChanged += lbFiles_SelectedIndexChanged;
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (OperationCanceledException) { }
            }
        }

        private void Form1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                RefreshEveryThing();
                btnXL.Enabled = true; btnMarks.Enabled = false;
                SourcePath = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop, false);
                

                if (SourcePath.Length == 1)
                {
                    XLPath = "";
                    AllFiles = Directory.GetFiles(SourcePath[0]).ToList();
                    string tmp = "";

                    foreach (string f in AllFiles)
                    {
                        tmp = f.Substring(f.LastIndexOf(@"\") + 1);
                        AllNamesOnly.Add(tmp);
                        lbFiles.Items.Add(tmp);
                    }
                    lbFiles.Sorted = true;

                    XLPath = SourcePath[0];
                }

            }
            catch { }
        }

        private void Form1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
                e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
            else
                e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;
        }


        private void StartMaximized(string FullFileName)
        {
            Process P = new Process();
            P.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
            P.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized;
            P.StartInfo.FileName = FullFileName;
            P.Start();
        }

        private void Sleeep(int s)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(s));
        }

        
        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            Cef.Shutdown();

            if (rbPDF.Checked == true) Properties.Settings.Default.PreviewMode = "PDF";
            else Properties.Settings.Default.PreviewMode = "HTML";
            Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
        }

        private void btnDec_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Point p = panel2.Location;
            lbFiles.Width -= ResizeUnit;
            panel2.Location = new Point(p.X - ResizeUnit, p.Y);
            //lblFCount.Location = new Point(p.X - ResizeUnit, lbFiles.Location.Y);
            panel2.Width += ResizeUnit;

        }

        private void btnInc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Point p = panel2.Location;
            lbFiles.Width += ResizeUnit;
            panel2.Location = new Point(p.X + ResizeUnit, p.Y);
            //lblFCount.Location = new Point(p.X + ResizeUnit, lbFiles.Location.Y);
            panel2.Width -= ResizeUnit;
        }

        private void RefreshEveryThing()
        {
            try
            {
                AllFiles.Clear();
                AllNamesOnly.Clear();
                lbFiles.Items.Clear();
                SourcePath = null;
                SelectedFile = "";
                NameOnly = "";

                wb.LoadUrl("about:blank");

                if (File.Exists(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\" + "output.html"))
                FileSystem.DeleteFile(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\" + "output.html", UIOption.OnlyErrorDialogs, RecycleOption.DeletePermanently);

                if (File.Exists(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\" + "output.pdf"))
                    FileSystem.DeleteFile(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\" + "output.pdf", UIOption.OnlyErrorDialogs, RecycleOption.DeletePermanently);

                //if (SourcePath!=null && SourcePath.Length == 1)
                //{
                //    AllFiles = Directory.GetFiles(SourcePath[0]).ToList();
                //    string tmp = "";

                //    foreach (string f in AllFiles)
                //    {
                //        tmp = f.Substring(f.LastIndexOf(@"\") + 1);
                //        AllNamesOnly.Add(tmp);
                //        lbFiles.Items.Add(tmp);
                //    }
                //}
            }
            catch { }
        }

        public void InitializeChromium()
        {
            CefSettings settings = new CefSettings();
            // Initialize cef with the provided settings
            Cef.Initialize(settings);
            // Create a browser component
            wb = new ChromiumWebBrowser("");

            // Add it to the form and fill it to the form window.
            this.panel2.Controls.Add(wb);
            wb.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        }


        #endregion

        private void btnMarks_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (lbFiles.SelectedIndex != -1)
            {
                Marks frmMarks = new Marks();
                frmMarks.ID = lbFiles.SelectedItem.ToString();
                frmMarks.XLFILE = XLPath;
                frmMarks.ShowDialog();

                if (frmMarks.MARKSENTERED == true)
                    lblFCount.Text = "Marks entered successfully";
                else
                    lblFCount.Text = "**Problem entering Marks**";

                frmMarks.Close();
            }
        }

        private void btnXL_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HSSFWorkbook hssfwb=null;
            
            try
            {
                if (Directory.Exists(SourcePath[0]))
                {
                    OpenFileDialog XL = new OpenFileDialog();
                    if (XLPath != String.Empty) XL.InitialDirectory = XLPath;
                    XL.Title = "Select Marks Sheet File";
                    XL.Filter = "Excel Files|*.xls;*.xlsx";
                    if (XL.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) XLPath = XL.FileName;

                    //Check old Excel File
                    if (XLPath.EndsWith(".xls"))
                    {
                        using (FileStream file = new FileStream(XLPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                        {
                            hssfwb = new HSSFWorkbook(file);
                            file.Close();
                        }

                        ISheet sheet = hssfwb.GetSheetAt(0);
                        try
                        {
                            if (sheet.GetRow(0).GetCell(0).StringCellValue != "StudentId" || sheet.GetRow(0).GetCell(1).StringCellValue != "Marks" || sheet.GetRow(0).GetCell(2).StringCellValue != "Comments")
                            {
                                MessageBox.Show("First sheet must have these three columns:\n\nStudentId  Marks  Comments");
                            }
                            else btnMarks.Enabled = true;
                        }
                        catch (NullReferenceException) { MessageBox.Show("First sheet must have these three columns:\n\nStudentId  Marks  Comments"); }
                    }                   
                }
            }
            catch { }
            finally
            {
                if (hssfwb!=null) hssfwb.Close();
                btnXL.Enabled = !btnMarks.Enabled;
            }

                       
        }

        private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Alt && e.KeyCode == Keys.M)
            {
                btnMarks.PerformClick();
                //btncash_Click(null, null);
            }
        }
    } // Name space and class ends
}
```